# Very slow PSQL query with several JOINs

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, query-optimization

I've been having problems with super slow query in PostgreSQL.

**DB ER diagram part focused in this problem**:

[image]

Table **culture** has 6 records, table **microclimate_value** has roughly **190k** records, table **location** has 3 records and table **crop_yield** has roughly **40k** records.

**Query**:

```
SELECT max(cy.value) AS yield, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cy.date) AS year
FROM microclimate_value AS mv
JOIN culture AS c ON mv.id_culture = c.id
JOIN location AS l ON mv.id_location = l.id
JOIN crop_yield AS cy ON l.id = cy.id_location
WHERE c.id = :cultureId AND l.id = :locationId
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year
```

This query should result with max value from (crop_yield table) for every year for given :cultureId (primary key from culture table) and :locationId (primary key from location table). It would look something like this (yield == value column from crop_yield table):

```
[
    {
        "year": 2014,
        "yield": 0.0
    },
    {
        "year": 2015,
        "yield": 1972.6590590838807
    },
    {
        "year": 2016,
        "yield": 3254.6370785040726
    },
    {
        "year": 2017,
        "yield": 2335.5804000689095
    },
    {
        "year": 2018,
        "yield": 3345.2244602819046
    },
    {
        "year": 2019,
        "yield": 3004.7096788680583
    },
    {
        "year": 2020,
        "yield": 2920.8721807693764
    },
    {
        "year": 2021,
        "yield": 0.0
    }
]
```

**Enhancement attempt**:

Initially, this query took around 10 minutes, so there is some big problem with optimization or with the query itself. The first thing I did was indexing foreign keys in **microclimate_value** and **crop_yield** table, which resulted in far better performance, but the query still takes 2-3 minutes to execute.

Does anyone have any tip on how to improve this? I am open for any tips, including changing the whole schema if needed, considering the fact I'm still learning SQL.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

1. Adding EXPLAIN PSQL

[image]

2. Adding second **EXPLAIN ANALYZE** PSQL after adding indexes:
   [image]

Comment: Can you post the output of an [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) of your query? This might reveal some slow operations that could be improved by an index.

Comment: @SebDieBln Edited the post with the result from EXPLAIN. Let me know if You want something more specific from this command.

Comment: Does creating an index for the `year` help? `CREATE INDEX ON "crop_yield" ((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "date")))`

Comment: @SebDieBln Added that index, but still: Total query runtime: 1 min 43 secs.

Comment: The "explain" shows a seq scan on `crop_yield` for the field `id_location`. Are you sure you have an index on that field?

Comment: Also there is a seq scan on `microclimate_value` for the fields `id_culture` and `id_location`. Try to add a multi-column index on these two columns `CREATE INDEX ON "microclimate_value" ("id_culture", "id_location")`.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS), that shows you the query plan and the places where you have issues. Just a query plan doesn't mean anything, it can be the best plan ever.

Comment: @SebDieBln For some reason Hibernate in SpringBoot didn't want to create indexes defined with annotations. However, after adding indexes manually with SQL to both id_culture and id_location in microclimate_value table and to id_location in crop_yield table, still the same duration: 1 min 41 secs. Once again ran EXPLAIN and the output is in the question.

Comment: By the way, the table "culture" is not needed at all. id_culture will do the trick, this will make the query slightly easier.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Added EXPLAIN ANALYZE to the post.

Comment: Could you please use plain text or a link to the query plan at https://explain.dalibo.com ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Not sure if I did that right but here's the plan: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/WUd.

Comment: This query makes no sense.  According to your diagram, crop_yield depends on the wider world exclusively through id_location.  And sense you are already specifying that value directly in your query via `:locationId`, there is no reason to do any joins, much less 3 of them.

Comment: @jjanes The query needs 2 parameters: cultureId and locationId. I can't query just with locationId. That's the point. I have to take into account somehow cultureId - and I've listened to FrankHeikens and removed JOIN with culture, so now I have lookup for cultureId on id_culture from microclimate_value table (= one less JOIN).

Comment: Given the id_location, you can look up the id_culture.  If any of the looked up value(s) agrees with the specified value, then the results are the same as if you didn't specify it (other than the slow speed).  And if they don't agree, then the result is zero rows.  Specifying the id_culture can't alter the results, other than by making them possibly empty (and likely much slower)

Comment: To me it looks like there is an issue with the datamodel and the tables microclimate_value and crop_yield could/should be merged into just one table. A fact-table in the OLAP world. This would also change the query, the indexes and of course the query plan.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I somehow understand what are You saying, but semantically that merge would not make sense. And yes, there is a possibility that data model is not entirely correct, but currently don't have any idea how to make it semantically better.

Comment: @jjanes How would you write this query having given parameters (cultureId and locationId) in order to extract maximum value from crop_yield grouped by years? So I need to get maximum yield values for a specific culture by years.

Answer (score 0):

Make some combinations of columns in a single index. I would start with this, to get rid of all the filtering after searching for the data:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_crop_yield_id_location_year_value ON crop_yield(id_location, (EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM DATE )), value);

CREATE INDEX idx_microclimate_value_id_location_id_culture ON microclimate_value(id_location, id_culture);
```

Maybe a different order in the columns works better, that's something you have to find out.

I would also leave the unused table "culture" out:

```
SELECT MAX( cy.VALUE ) AS yield,
    EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM cy.DATE ) AS YEAR 
FROM
    microclimate_value AS mv
        JOIN LOCATION AS l ON mv.id_location = l.ID 
        JOIN crop_yield AS cy ON l.ID = cy.id_location 
WHERE
    mv.id_culture = : cultureId 
AND l.ID = : locationId 
GROUP BY    YEAR 
ORDER BY    YEAR;
```

And after every change in the query or the indexes, run EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) again.

Comment: 1. This resulted in query time around 1min 10sec, still problematic.
2. Do I need to remove previously created indexes when changing columns order?

Comment: Yes, you could delete some indexes. But you have to use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)  over and over again. Nobody can help you without that information, we don't have access to your database

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `explain analyze` there are 10,970 rows of `microclimate_value` for `location=2 and id_culture=1`. Also there are 12,316 rows for `location=2` in `crop_yield`.

As there is no other condition for join of those 2 tables, the database has to create in memory a table with 10,970*12,316=135,106,520 rows and then group its results. It might take some time…

I think you are missing some condition in your query. Are you sure there should not be the same date on microclimate_value.date and crop_yield.date? Because, IMHO, without it, the query does not make much sense.

---

If there's no connection with those dates, then the only information that might be useful in microclimate_value is whether matching `location_id=? and culture_id=?` exists there:

```
select
  max(value) as max_value,
  extract(year from date) as year,
from crop_yield
where location_id=?
  and exists(
    select 1
    from microclimate_value
    where location_id=? and culture_id=?
  )
group by year
```

You'll either get results, if they match somewhere, or won't get any. The design of this schema seems questionable.

Comment: No, there is no condition on dates equality on those two tables. I got You why it doesn't make sense, but how would You write a query on the current state of DB with given parameters (cultureId and locationId) in order to extract maximum value from crop_yield grouped by years?

Comment: I tried to clarify it somewhat.